# "Sequence contains no elements" - Optional foreign key

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework

I've just manually added foreign key ID's to my entities.

My UserProfile entity used to have the following properties:

```
public virtual UserProfile Referer { get; set; }
```

So now my UserProfile entity has the following properties:

```
[ForeignKey("Referer")]
public int? RefererId { get; set; }

public virtual UserProfile Referer { get; set; }
```

However when I update the database I get the following error:

> *Sequence contains no elements*

The Referer UserProfile is supposed to be optional which is why I marked the int?.

What's the issue here?

Edit the UserProfile ID field looks the following:

```
[Key]
[DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
public int UserId { get; set; }
```

Comment: I don't uderstand, does your UserProfile Entity contain property of same type?

Comment: @KirillBestemyanov
Well it can optionally reference another UserProfile. That's pretty much it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've misused `ForeignKey` attribute. It should be applied on your virtual property to define database field which contains `RefererId`. 
So in your case it should be something like:

```
public int? RefererId { get; set; }

[ForeignKey("RefererId")]
public virtual UserProfile Referer { get; set; }
```

---

***UPDATE***:
I suppose that this should be an One-to-Many relationship. So you'll have to update your class to have corresponding structure. I've created sample solution with pretty much same structure:

```
    public class Person
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int PersonId { get; set; }

        [ForeignKey("PersonId")]
        public Person Supervisor { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Person> SupervisedPersons { get; set; }
    }

    public class PersonDataContext : DbContext
    {
        public DbSet<Person> Persons { get; set; }
        protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
            modelBuilder.Entity<Person>()
                .HasKey(x => x.PersonId)
                .HasOptional(op => op.Supervisor)
                .WithMany(p => p.SupervisedPersons)
                .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
        }
    }
```

Comment: @JordanAxe Do you have any `Key` field in `UserProfile`(some Id)?

Comment: @JordanAxe What kind of relationship are you trying to achieve by such structure? One-to-one or One-to-Many?

Comment: Each userprofile can contain an optional reference to another userprofile.

Comment: @JordanAxe So it could also contain `0..n` referenced profiles (those that were using it as an `Referer`).

Comment: Sorry for the late reply.
Well the referer doesn't reference the userprofile that has it as referer. Each userprofile can contain 0..1 Userprofiles

Comment: I'm getting past the error now but I get an error trying to update it.

The constraint 'PK_dbo.UserProfile' is being referenced by table 'webpages_UsersInRoles', foreign key constraint 'fk_UserId'.
Could not drop constraint. See previous errors.

Comment: @JordanAxe If you're using mixed EF code first and already built in ASP.NET MVC UserRoles structure you'll have to update `Up()/Down()` migrations with custom cleanup code to support both.